Unable to push from within GitHub Actions job
Currently, I have a GitHub action job where it updates the version of the NPM package, commits the changes, and pushes to the remote repo.
Here is the job responsible for this part:
update_package_version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:                # Job-level permissions configuration starts here
      contents: write           # 'write' access to repository contents
      pull-requests: write      # 'write' access to pull requests
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.0

    - name: Update package
      run: |
        local_branch_name=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
        github_branch_name=${{ github.ref }}

        git config --global user.email ${{vars.UserEmail}}
        git config --global user.name ${{vars.UserName}}

        if [[ $local_branch_name =~ --Major$ || $github_branch_name =~ --Major$ ]]; then
          echo "Updating package.json version to a major release"
          npm version major --no-git-tag-version
        elif [[ $local_branch_name =~ --Minor$ || $github_branch_name =~ --Minor$ ]]; then
          echo "Updating package.json version to a minor release"
          npm version minor --no-git-tag-version
        elif [[ $local_branch_name =~ --Patch$ || $github_branch_name =~ --Patch$ ]]; then
          echo "Updating package.json version to a patch release"
          npm version patch --no-git-tag-version
        else
          echo "No version update required for the current branch"
        fi

        git add package.json
        git add package-lock.json
        git commit -m "Update package.json version" --allow-empty
        git push --verbose

The problem with the job above is that when it comes to pushing, it keeps on pushing and nothing happens. I get the following output and it never ends:
| \[test-pipeline--Minor ee02442\] Update package.json version
|  2 files changed, 6284 insertions(+), 6284 deletions(-)
| Pushing to https://github.com/%7Borganization_name%7D/%7Brepo_name%7D

I checked that there are no branch protection rules yet still the same result.
Important notes:

I test out the GitHub action locally using act

The branch name is test-pipeline--Minor

The configured user email and user name are as the git configs I have locally on my PC and they are also the same as my GitHub account

The workflow is set on workflow_dispatch and the main branch doesn't have GitHub actions yet all of this is done on other branches

If I used the git add. command instead of adding the package.json and package-lock.json I get a lot of files committed which I have no explanation for.



Here's an example of similar scenario (see here and here).

@Azeem are the git creds ( user.email, user.name) used in the example above a default I can use right away or do they need need to be configured or generated first ?

be sure to add with: fetch-depth: 0  to the checkout task: https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches

@KarimFayed: You may use your own that you need. Those are the default ones that I normally use.
